# Can't access data from the Users table from a function in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to use a function to soft delete 2 rows in a database, one is from a table I made called `persona` and the other one is from the `users` table that laravel makes with Auth, My users table have a foreign key associated to the `persona` table called `idPersona`. What I'm trying to do is to soft delete the row from the `persona` table that matches the `id` parameter and after that soft delete the row in `users` where the attribute `idPersona` matches the `id` parameter that the function recieved.

I'm going to post the Controller function code

**Controller function code**

```
 public function deleteMedico($id){
        $medico = Persona::findOrFail($id);
        $medico->estado =False;
        $personaID = $medico->id;
        $user= new User();
        $user->where('idPersona',$personaID);
        var_dump($user);
        
    }
```

I'm going to try to explain what I'm trying to do with this controller, I use the findOrFail function to find the row I'm trying to self delete from the `persona` table, after I found it I set `estado` to false in this way soft deleting the row. After that I try to get an User instance, look for the `users` table where idPersona matches the id of the row that was soft deleted.

The code for self deleting it would be almost the same than with the `persona` table but the problem is I can't find the row in the `users` table, gonna post the `var_dump` I get of `$user`.

[image: var_dump of $users]

Also gonna post how my database looks in case it is useful

[image: Database diagram]

I have no idea what I need to do to get the row of the `users` table where the `idPersona` attribute matches the `id` attribute from the `personas` table. I'm new in Laravel so sorry if this question is repetitive or is nothing to hard. p

Comment: Don't create a new user instance. Do `$user = User::where('idPersona',$personaID)->first();` or (even better) create an eloquent relationship between `Persona` and `User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```php
// $user = new User();
// $user->where('idPersona',$personaID);
$user = User::where('idPersona', $personaID)->firstOrFail();
```

This should fix the syntax but there are simpler ways to do this in your code.

---

Route model binding

```php
Route::get('deleteMedico/{persona}', ...);
```

Eloquent Relationships

```php
// Persona.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'idPersona');
}
```

```php
public function deleteMedico(Persona $persona)
{
     $persona->fill(['estado' => false])->save();
     $persona->user->fill(['estado' => false])->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. I tried before with the get() method but it didn't worked. Maybe I had the logic before it wrong and now I forgot to include it.

Comment: get() returns a collection. first()/firstOrFail() returns a model.

Comment: so that's why it wasn't working with get() then. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the get method.

`User::where('idPersona',$personaID)->get();`

Comment: thanks for your help but as pointed out by IGP above the get method doesn't help in this case, the first or fail option was the right one.